# how <div {...props}/> and <div>{props.children}</div> are same in react

Tags: reactjs

```
const AppRendrer =(props)=>(<div {...props}/>)

class App extends  React.Component{
  render(){
    return <AppRendrer>This is test</AppRendrer>
  }
}


export default App;
```

Output of above is "This is test" if i use `<div {...props}/>`

```
const AppRendrer =(props)=>(<div>{props.children}</div>)

class App extends  React.Component{
  render(){
    return <AppRendrer>This is test</AppRendrer>
  }
}


export default App;
```

Output of above is also "This is test" if i use {props.children}

can any on explain how `<div {...props}/> and <div>{props.children}</div>` are same

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSX is syntactic sugar for `React.createElement`, children of React element are translated to `children` prop due to the way how `createElement` works.

```
<p className="class">foo</p>
```

is transformed to

```
React.createElement('p', { className: 'class' }, 'foo');
```

It's the same thing as:

```
React.createElement('p', { className: 'class', children: 'foo' });
```

Both result in React element object:

```
{ type: 'p', props: { className: 'class', children: 'foo' }, ... }
```

`createElement` supports children as separate arguments in order to make it more concise when it's used without JSX:

```
React.createElement('p', null,
  React.createElement('b', null,
   'foo'
  )
);
```

`<div {...props}/>` and `<div>{props.children}</div>` are not the same. `<div {...props}/>` passes all props while `<div>{props.children}</div>` passes only `children`. They work the same way only because there were no other props.

They would be the same if they were `<div children={props.children}/>` and `<div>{props.children}</div>` .

Answer (score 1):

In React, nesting components like this:

```
<ComponentA>
    <ComponentB />
</ComponentA>
```

...is treated the same as if you'd passed a prop called `children`:

```
<ComponentA children={<ComponentB />} />
```

In your first example, you're passing *all* of the props from `AppRendrer` down to the `div` element (via the prop spread syntax) - this includes the `children`, if present.